# Convert Pdf response from API Call to Blob and generate Blob Url

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I am trying to convert the response to blob and then generate url to access that. The response from the get request is Pdf.

Here's what I am doing.

```
this.$http.get<string>(
        invoicePath
      ).then((response:any)=> {
        console.log("CREATING A BLOB")
        console.log("RESPONSE BLOB: ", response.data); 
        const blob:any = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8' });
        console.log("RESPONSE BLOB: ", blob);
        const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // window.open(url);
        return url
        //window.location.href = response.url;
      })
```

The url returned gives me the below error message.
[image]

Comment: try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to convert the response to ArrayBuffer first.

```
this.$http.get<string>(
        invoicePath, {responseType:'arraybuffer'}
      ).then((response:any)=> {
        console.log("CREATING A BLOB")
        console.log("RESPONSE BLOB: ", response.data); 
        const blob:any = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8' });
        console.log("RESPONSE BLOB: ", blob);
        const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // window.open(url);
        return url
        //window.location.href = response.url;
      })
```